# Pine Script How do you create alert with 3 conditions

Tags: pine-script

I'm looking for pine script condition to plot alert on chart based on below 3 condition.

Timeframe = 5 min or 15 min (User Modify)

Condition: Higher Higher + Higher Low + Close Price

Candle High > Previous Candle High => high > high[1] => High is Greater than Previous Candle High
Candle Low > Previous Candle Low => low > low [1] => Low is Greater than Previous Candle Low
Candle Close> Previous Candle close => close > high [1] => close is Greater than Previous Candle High

Alert should trigger whenever such condition met. Chart Timeframe can be 5 min or 15 min.

Please help to advise.

Thank you,
Karthik M

I'm able to trigger this individually, but couldn't get together.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to trigger them individually, then you just need to `and` or `or` them.

If you want to get an alert when ALL those three conditions are met at the same time, you should use the `and` operator.

If you want to receive an alert when at least one of those conditions is satisfied, then you should use the `or` operator.

```
alert_me = higher_high_cond and higher_low_cond and close_price_cond
alertcondition(alert_me, "Alert")
```